# Adding Html tag doubles my paragraph

Tags: html

I have this weird situation.
Whenever I add the html tag, my paragraph just below the html tag doubles itself on publishing.
Here is the html tag

```html
<font color="red">少量のみの再入荷となっております。お求めの方はお早めにどうぞ</font>
```

And here is the paragraph that doubles itself on publishing, but the source file is just showing normal, not doubled.

```html
パートナーとの刺激的な愛を求める「情熱」ローション
パートナーと二人きりで過ごす時間。
たまにはまるで映画の中の1シーンのように、熱く刺激的な愛の時間を過ごしたいですよね。
AZ Lilyローション Yは、イランイランのエキスを配合することで濃厚で甘くセクシーな香りが官能的な気分を高め、情熱的な愛を演出します。

<h3>使い方</h3>
お好みで500円玉大くらいを手に取って、優しくパートナーの性感帯を指の腹や手のひらでマッサージしてください。
最初は、背中や首筋、胸などと、段々と敏感な部分へ伸ばしていくと、ヌルヌル感と滑る感覚が気持ちよく、エロティックな気分を高めることができます。
また、お互いにマッサージし合うと、より愛を高めることができるでしょう。
特に、性感帯は塗った部分が敏感になり、ただ触れるだけでも極上の気持ちよさを味わうことができます。
シチュエーションに合わせてローションの香りを変えたりしながら楽しみ方を見つけてみてください。
```

Final output screenshot [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/fSttiz)

Comment: use a `<p>` tag

Comment: hard to understand your language

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Anything (almost) can be a tag in HTML5, though in this situation it would make more sense as a `p` or a `span`. But I don't think that's related to this particular problem (Though, I can't seem to repo the problem at all with the current code)

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Where exactly do you put that `<font>` tag? Can you show us an example code which reproduces your problem?

Comment: @DBS ah fair enough :) either way, using standarised tags can cause fewer problems (as to my understanding,every browser knows how to render `<p>` tags)